# Environment variables in Dagster config YAML

Tags: dagster

I'm attempting to provide an environment variable in a config YAML file as such:

```yaml
resources:
  be_warehouse:
    config:
      conn_str:
        env: DB_CONN_STR
  analytics_warehouse:
    config:
      conn_str:
        env: WH_DB_CONN_STR
```

but I am receiving the following error:

```
Invalid scalar at path root:resources:analytics_warehouse:config:conn_str. Value "{'env': 'WH_DB_CONN_STR'}" of type "<class 'dict'>" is not valid for expected type "String".
```

I have seen this syntax used in [this official example](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/blob/0.11.4/examples/airline_demo/airline_demo/environments/test_base.yaml). Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `env: ENV_VAR` support is available for config schema which is typed as `StringSource`. If these are `@resource`s you are creating you just need to declare `config_schema={'conn_str': StringSource}` instead of just using `str`.

https://docs.dagster.io/_apidocs/config#dagster.StringSource